# Setting a value of a field in my table for future use

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have an access Db which was originally written ib Access 2003 but has since been upgraded to Access 2007 - the problem I am experiencing is as follows:

I have a table "tblBookings" which stores all relevant data for a particular clienst booking or quote, the client field of this table is linked to the PK of the CLient Table (tblClients) when a quote is accepted the user opens the main form, selects the client and in a dropdown selects the booking number then proceeds to "Edit booking" where the user can either edit the booking or confirm it. when the user clicks "confirm Booking" cmdButton the open form closes and the "Create Invoice" form opens. From a dropdown list the user selects the booking number and then prints the Pro-Forma Invoice or invoice. the print pro-forma cammand button opens a report that prints the necessary document, when the Print Invoice command is clicked then the print invoice form is opend where the user has the option to record any ayments made against the invoice.

This being said it is essential to first print a pro-forma before printing an invoice so i need to set a yes no field in the table to yes or true if a pro forma has been printed in which case the invoice button will become visible and remain hidden if one has not been printed yet.

the event procedure on cmdProForma is below (this is where I need ti set the yes/no field in the Pro field which is tblBookings and set to a yes/no field.

```
Private Sub CmdProForma_Click()
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset 'recordset of existing refs
    Dim t As String 'temp string var
    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String
    Dim i As Integer 'temp ref variable

       i = CInt(Right(txtBRef, 5))
       t = [txtBRef]


   With rs
      .Open "SELECT BRef,Conf,lock,Pro FROM tblBookings WHERE Bref=" & t & ";", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic
      If .BOF Or .EOF Then 'no such ref
      MsgBox "No booking with ref '" & fRef(CInt(t), "B") & "' exists.", vbExclamation, "No booking"
      Else 'ref found: open invoice
      strSQL = "UPDATE tblBookings SET Pro = True"

'db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
      DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmBRefEnter"
        ' !Form!frmBRefEnter!Pro = True
      DoCmd.OpenReport "rptInvoice1", acViewPreview, , "BRef=" & t
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptInvoice1", acFormatPDF, destDIR & "\Inv\" & fRef(i, "Pro-Forma") & ".pdf"

           End If

      End With

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the checkbox for proforma printed to the form. It will be a good guide for your users as to why they cannot print an invoice. You can set the properties to Locked=True

```
Private Sub CmdProForma_Click()
    ''"From a dropdown list the user selects the booking number", 
    ''so the booking number must exist, no need to check
      DoCmd.OpenReport "rptInvoice1", acViewPreview, , "BRef=" & Me.txtBref
      DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptInvoice1", _
          acFormatPDF, destDIR & "\Inv\" & fRef(i, "Pro-Forma") & ".pdf"
      Me.Pro = True ''Checkbox
      DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmBRefEnter"
End Sub
```

For the invoice button:

```
Me.cmdInvoicePrint.Visible = Me.Pro
```

If Me.Pro is ticked, Me.Pro will be true and the invoice button will be visible.

Comment: I will try this immediatly and revert with comment - thank you so far

Comment: ok I have added that to the code, however, the Checkbox "Pro" remains unchecked once the code has run - what am I missing?

Comment: Is your checkbox called Me.Pro? Is the code running in the form module? Is the checkbox bound to the appropriate field in your table? This  `Me.Pro = True` is the line intended to set the checkbox to true, but it must match your set up.

Comment: ok the check box on the form is set to visible = false so nobody can check it by mistake the field is unbound ( I did try it bound but to no avail) and yes the line Me.Pro = True is indeed the line that is intended to se the check box to true value.